# How to add styles to React Component with a for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styling

I'm wanting to set the top style of each React component relative to its index in the array, however, I am unsure how to access and set the property correctly. I would set them using state, however, the node containing the element which I want to manipulate is a child node of a sibling node from the node which I am editing from. Any way to do this effectively?

```
handleClick3D() {
    document.getElementById('portfolio').classList.replace('portfolio-2d', 'portfolio-3d');
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-item');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        var zIndex = 0 + i;
        elems[i].zIndex = zIndex;
        elems[i].firstChild.src = items[i].imgSec;
        elems[i].style.top = 0 - (i * 300);
    }
}
```

The 'portfolio-item' class is applied to each element and I am selecting each element that way as I don't think I can access the actual React component seeing as it lives in a sibling node tree.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use .map function and return jsx component with different style or props

Comment: it looks like your doing this in an off way. you shouldnt need to access the dom as part of a click handler to change your react components, you'd want you click event to change the components `state` and for that change to go to child components as updated props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use .map function and return jsx component with different style or props

[link](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)